# MySql Access Violation or Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, access-violation

I'm getting the following error when I try to execute the sql statement below it.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like, agree, favor, discriminator) VALUES ('5023fb89189df', 0, '2012-08-09 14:03' at line 1
```

The full sql statement is below

```
INSERT INTO activity (id, hide_author, created, updated, access, location, disabled, created_ip, updated_ip, params, body, audit, hide_activity, author, owning_activity, like, agree, favor, discriminator) VALUES ('5023fa5a63d1b', NULL, '2012-08-09 13:58:50', '2012-08-09 13:58:50', NULL, NULL, 0, '192.168.1.1', NULL, NULL, 'Exactly, I would prefer to be able to defend myself when the unthinkable happens', NULL, 0, '50143c83e3f5a', '5023e63dafe18', 1, NULL, NULL, 'commentpost')
```

I don't see any errors with the syntax, but maybe you guys can give some suggestions as to what kind of access violations could be the cause. What should I look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Like" is a reserved word in SQL. Encase it in backticks. That's the key next to the "1" on your computer like so:

```
INSERT INTO activity (id, hide_author, created, updated, access, location, disabled, created_ip, updated_ip, params, body, audit, hide_activity, author, owning_activity, `like`, agree, favor, discriminator) VALUES ('5023fa5a63d1b', NULL, '2012-08-09 13:58:50', '2012-08-09 13:58:50', NULL, NULL, 0, '192.168.1.1', NULL, NULL, 'Exactly, I would prefer to be able to defend myself when the unthinkable happens', NULL, 0, '50143c83e3f5a', '5023e63dafe18', 1, NULL, NULL, 'commentpost')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the ultra-quick response. it looks like I'll have to change the name of the attribute though. I'm doing this through Doctrine afterall. unless you know of a way to get Doctrine to add those ticks?

Comment: If it is in any way possible for you to change the name of the field, I highly recommend you do so. I'm not familiar with Doctrine, I'm afraid, but regardless, changing the name would be recommended.